# SpringSecurity - Best way to disable to perform "fake login"

Tags: spring-security

I would like to find the best/elegant/handy way to enable/disable spring security for test and dev environment. I would like to use a property on db, if this property is set to ON then the authentication is mandatory, otherwise the user does not need to authenticate and it reaches the application homepage directly with all roles associated and fake user name/properties.

By the way, my application has a simple authentication strategy: the user logged previously via a different web-application that provides him links to access many other web-app. One of this link redirect to my web-app with a simple submit containing user name and roles, my security chain catches this informations and perform an automatic authentication.

Any suggestion will be appreciated ;)

Bye!
Dolfiz

Some snippet of my code...

SpringSecurityContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/fakeLogin*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/authError*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/VAADIN**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="http://milan-ias-vs.usersad.everis.int/DMTest/" invalidate-session="true" />
        <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilter" />
    </security:http>

    <bean id="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint" class="it.ram.authentication.LinkForbiddenEntryPoint" />

    <bean id="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilter" class="it.ram.authentication.PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
            <bean class="it.ram.authentication.PreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:

```
public class PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

    private final static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);

    public PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter() {
        super();
        log.debug("PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter default constructor");
        setAuthenticationDetailsSource(new CustomAuthenticationDetailsSource());
    }

    public PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        log.debug("PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter constructor with AuthMan arg");
        setAuthenticationDetailsSource(new CustomAuthenticationDetailsSource());
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String userName = request.getParameter(Constants.REQUEST_USER_PARAM);
        log.debug("getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal - Returning " +userName);
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.debug("getPreAuthenticatedCredentials - Returning N/A");
        return "N/A";
    }

    public static class CustomAuthenticationDetailsSource implements AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest, SessionUserDetails> {

        @Override
        public SessionUserDetails buildDetails(HttpServletRequest request) {
            log.debug("buildDetails");
            // create container for pre-auth data
            String role = request.getParameter(Constants.REQUEST_ROLE_PARAM);
            return new SessionUserDetails(role);
        }
    }
}
```

PreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService.xml:

```
public class PreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> {

    private final static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(PreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService.class);

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserDetails(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken  token) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        log.debug("loadUserDetails - token.getName(): " +token.getName());

        SessionUserDetails sessionUserDetails = (SessionUserDetails) token.getDetails();
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = sessionUserDetails.getAuthorities();            
        return new User(token.getName(), "N/A", true, true, true, true, authorities);
    }

}
```

Comment: Fake login ?  like an Anonymous user token ?  Login is nothing special you need to perform a few operations and add a usable token into the HttpSession.  You can drive standard Spring Security APIs manually to do this.

Comment: As I guessed, so the simple/clean way could be modifying my PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter in order to check a property on db and eventually perform a manual authentication ignoring the form submit, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at:

org.springframework.security.web.authentication.RememberMeServices#autoLogin(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)

Poke around here for an implementation:

http://git.springsource.org/spring-security/spring-security/trees/c12c43da9eb59b664bc995a38859c6acac621390/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme

SecurityContextHolder is the place to look if you have existing credentials and to then change or replace them.

```
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
// authentication contains existing (if set and non-null) maybe it is anonymous
// so then you might have a better set of credentials to replace it with
WebappUserDetails webappUserDetails = userContextService.getPrincipal(WebappUserDetails.class);
// The above constructs my custom type that implement spring UserDetails interface
// this is the identity of the user
// You should check things are valid (account enable and valid, etc..)
// Then you make a fake Authentication and attach it to the session context
// There are many token kinds in spring representing different ways to auth
//  this token is the kind that might be used for a HTML form based login with
//  username and password. 
String principal = "myusername";  // username
String credentials = "mypassword";  // password
// Note you should probably not want to hardwire passwords into code and the correct
//  way is to setup a new Token type and configure main security XML to allow it
//  to the secure URLs (or secured subjects)
Authentication authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, credentials);
Authentication authResult = authenticationManager.authenticate(authRequest);
// Check the authResult then attach it to the context
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);
```